# About /proc/kpageflags file

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, shared-memory, ram

/proc/kpageflags.  This file contains a 64-bit set of flags for each
   page, indexed by PFN.

The flags are (from fs/proc/page.c, above kpageflags_read):

```
 0. LOCKED
 1. ERROR
 2. REFERENCED
 3. UPTODATE
 4. DIRTY
 5. LRU
 6. ACTIVE
 7. SLAB
 8. WRITEBACK
 9. RECLAIM
10. BUDDY
11. MMAP
12. ANON
13. SWAPCACHE
14. SWAPBACKED
15. COMPOUND_HEAD
16. COMPOUND_TAIL
17. HUGE
18. UNEVICTABLE
19. HWPOISON
20. NOPAGE
21. KSM
22. THP
23. BALLOON
24. ZERO_PAGE
25. IDLE
```

I have got the flags on the physical memory page, how do I know if the page is dirty?

I thought it was flags & (1<< 4) and I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 64-bit flags are in flags variable

`if((flags >> 4) & 0x1)
    return true;   //page is dirty`

I guess this logic should tell if a page is dirty or not